# Problem with Many To Many RelationShip Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring

I'm using Spring boot as the backend of my application but I have a problem here.

This is my Entity relationship diagram:

[image: Entity relationship diagram]

And these are my classes

Product class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="productos")
public class Producto implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@NotEmpty
@Size(max=45)
@Column(nullable=false,unique=true) 
private String name;
@Column(nullable =false)
private String descripcion;

@Column(nullable = false)
private float precio;

@Column(nullable=false,length = 255)
private String urlFoto;

@Column(nullable=false)
private float calorias;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(
        name = "Producto_Ingrediente",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_producto")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_ingrediente")}
)
private List<Ingrediente> ingredientes;
//getters and setters
```

Ingrediente class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredientes")
public class Ingrediente implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String nombre;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredientes", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Producto> productos;
//getters and setters
```

But when i try to recover my products from the API, look at this json (its from CrudRepository)

```
{
"id": 2,
"name": "pancakes",
"descripcion": "aaaaa",
"precio": 10.0,
"urlFoto": "no hay",
"calorias": 2.0,
"ingredientes": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "miel",
        "productos": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "pancakes",
                "descripcion": "aaaaa",
                "precio": 10.0,
                "urlFoto": "no hay",
                "calorias": 2.0,
                "ingredientes": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "nombre": "miel",
                        "productos": [
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "pancakes",
                                "descripcion": "aaaaa",
                                "precio": 10.0,
                                "urlFoto": "no hay",
                                "calorias": 2.0,
                                "ingredientes": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 2,
                                        "nombre": "miel",
                                        "productos": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 2,
                                                "name": "pancakes",
                                                "descripcion": "aaaaa",
                                                "precio": 10.0,
                                                "urlFoto": "no hay",
                                                "calorias": 2.0,
                                                "ingredientes": [
```

and it continues, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson, you could try to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties("ingredientes")` above the `private List<Producto> productos;`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredientes", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("ingredientes")
private List<Producto> productos;
```